# What drain line can I use for a basement utility washtub?

Tags: plumbing, drain

I'm planning on installing a basement utility washtub in my woodshop, and finding a suitable drain is the main obstacle in placement of the tub. What should I be looking for in terms of a proper drain line?

First, here is option 1, 4" (?) drain line. Can I just tap into the cleanout, install a T and a P trap?

[image]

Option 2, I'm not sure what this would be for. 2" line, it's a drain, right?
[image]

Comment: Definitely can't tap into the cleanout. Not sure what the 2" standing pipe is, are there stubouts for water near there? If a plumber were doing the job, he would tie into the stack but cutting a section and glueing in a wye. (can't tell if the stack is PVC)

Comment: The stack is PVC. Nothing around the standing pipe

Comment: I would just cut the stack and prime and glue a new wye fitting to drain the utility sink.

Comment: Odds are good that if you cut into the main stack and put in a Wye there, the stack would function as a wet vent for your sink. (Don't forget, you're going to need a vent for that sink!)